# How can I add custom UIControl subclasses graphically in IB in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to use [Matthijs Hollemans' MHRotaryKnob](http://www.hollance.com/2010/12/mhrotaryknob-a-rotary-knob-control-for-ios/) control in my iOS 5 app. I am using a storyboard in Xcode 4.2. `MHRotaryKnob` is implemented as a subclass of `UIControl`.

I'm unable to replicate the example he provides and thus unable to add the control to my app's view. In the example, his XIB contains a view with an instance of `MHRotaryKnob` added to it as a custom control. It loads and runs fine but I can see no way in Xcode to do this for myself. I've tried adding every kind of `UIControl` subclass and changing their class in the Identity Inspector, but Xcode keeps changing them right back.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a special framework he is using.

Comment: Sharky, can you elaborate? I know he's using Quartz but how's that affect whats not happening in IB? Thanks

Comment: No sorry I can't. It was something I read about at the very beginning of my app development and I can't clearly remember that. And I don't really like the IB, too. I would just implement the control programmatically. Just google a bit about frameworks and the controls for the IB. Sorry again.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is to add a UIView to the view and change its class in the Identity Inspector, rather than trying to do that with buttons or other UIControls.

Answer (score 1):

When you changed the class of the UIView from the Identity Inspector, don't forget to add  **initWithCoder:aDecoder** to your code, in the custom class.