# How to modify UIControl framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrol

I'm using this framework [HRColorPicker](http://hayashi311.github.io/Color-Picker-for-iOS/). I want to layout it's subviews in Autolayout in Storyboard, but can't figure out how the framework works.

It's main class is a subclass of `UIControl` called `HRColorPickerView` with 3 properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView <HRColorInfoView> *colorInfoView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIControl <HRColorMapView> *colorMapView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIControl <HRBrightnessSlider> *brightnessSlider;
```

Each of these has it's own class and each is one of 3 subviews in the picker.

I want to create a `UIViewController` with this color picker in it. If I just make a plain `UIView` and add it to a `UIViewController` in Storyboard and set it's type to `HRColorPickerView`, I get the default color picker and it works just fine. The author of the framework says that those properties are customizable and even has a shot of them in Storyboard. But I have no idea how to get them into my Storyboard so I can customize them.

However, I want to use Storyboard to lay out the subviews/properties with Autolayout. Basically, I want to create my own views in a VC, set them as one of the 3 types and lay them out in Storyboard. I tried setting the views' type to each of the 3 when I connect them to the .h file, but when I run, I get crashes and I don't think I'm doing it right. I create 2 `UIView`s and 1 `UISlider`, each one as one of the 3 properties. The `UISlider` gets "unrecognized selector" crashes, which shouldn't happen since the class backing the views should be able to handle it.

This is my .h file and in Storyboard, the 3 properties below *colorPickerView are subviews of *colorPickerView.

```
@interface ColorPickerViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet HRColorPickerView *colorPickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet HRColorMapView *colorMap;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet HRColorInfoView *colorInfo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet HRBrightnessSlider *brightSlider;

@end
```

Comment: At the bottom of the page you have liked (http://hayashi311.github.io/Color-Picker-for-iOS/) it is described how to costumes the UI.

Comment: @dasdom it does say that you can, however, it does not how how to do it. The UISlider code that it does show didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the author of the lib?

Comment: @dasdom yep. Don't know how regularly he checks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the author, so these are my guess really. It is a bit confusing of the library code, as the protocols share the same name with the actual classes.

According to the screenshot, add a UI component and set the custom class *is* the correct way to do it. However, I believe the error happened to your slider is due to the fact that `HRBrightnessSlider` is a subclass of `UIControl`, so you can't drag in a `UISlider` into the view. According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8227300/2710486), you need to drag in another `UIView` instead.

If you really want to write your own slider, you can drag and use a `UISlider` by conforming `HRBrightnessSlider` protocol.

Comment: thanks, i'll give it a try and let you know what happens. YES, the protocol names were killing me!